# How to store Python dictionary with QSettings

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qsettings

The code below stores Python `data` dictionary using `QSettings` object.
After reading it back the dictionary comes with all its keys as `QString` like so:

```
{PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'one'): 1, PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'two'): 2}
```

I wonder if it would be possible to read the dictionary with a regular string keys like this:

```
{'one': 1, 'two': 2}
```

Code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

settings = QtCore.QSettings('apps', 'settings')

data = {'one': 1, 'two': 2}

settings.setValue('data', data)

data = settings.value('data').toPyObject()
print data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Python2**

Is not possible directly, you have to convert them to a regular dictionary.

```
d = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    d[str(k)] = v
```

**Complete code:**

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

settings = QtCore.QSettings('apps', 'settings')

data = {'one': 1, 'two': 2}

settings.setValue('data', data)

data = settings.value('data').toPyObject()
d = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    d[str(k)] = v

print(d)
```

output:

```
{'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

- **Python3**

This problem does not exist since it returns you a regular dictionary, it is no longer necessary to convert it with toPyObject().

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

settings = QtCore.QSettings('apps', 'settings')

data = {'one': 1, 'two': 2}

settings.setValue('data', data)

data = settings.value('data')
print(data)
```

output:

```
 {'one': 1, 'two': 2}
```

Comment: It is possible to do this in Python 2. All you need to do is use [sip.setapi](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatible_apis.html) to get the same behaviour as Python 3. I don't know why anyone would want to keep those nasty `QString` and `QVariant` types in their code. Converting with `str()` is also buggy in Python 2 - you should always use `unicode()` to do the conversion in order to avoid decode/encode errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
original = {PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'one'): 1, PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'two'): 2}
converted = {str(k): val for k, v in original.items()}
```

Comment: This is really too brief to be useful, especially compared with the other, much more comprehensive answer. Explanation should be added.